# Apps Mobile, Azure e AWS

Tags: amazon-aws, microsoft-azure, hospedagem, google-play, appstore

Olá,
Ao criar um app e colocá-lo na AppStore ou na GooglePlay, devo ainda, dependendo do tipo de aplicativo, adquirir algum serviço de hospedagem mobile em serviços como Azure ou AWS para deixar por exemplo, o banco de dados do meu aplicativo?

Ou estas lojas hospedam "todo" o meu aplicativo? Inclusive o crescimento exponencial dos dados gerados pelo app.

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com  *estas lojas hospedam "todo" o meu aplicativo?*?

Comment: Desculpe Marco, mas minha pergunta pode ser muito óbvia para vocês da comunidade, porém pra mim é básico. Quero dizer com o "todo", a parte de trás do aplicativo. Inclusive os dados gerados. Exemplo: O aplicativo permite que você entre através do login das redes sociais e envie uma foto para o aplicativo. Essa foto será armazenada nos servidores Apple (caso desenvolva para IOS)  ou minha estrutura de app deve conter o caminho para o banco de dados que pode estar na AWS ou Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stores só disponibilizarão o seu aplicativo para download.

Você deverá tratar todo o resto por conta própria.

(O Google por exemplo oferece um serviço de back-end as a service chamado Firebase).

Porém a Store é só um local para conseguirem seu APP mesmo. :)

Comment: Legal Lucas. era exatamente esta minha pergunta. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, considere dar um Upvote ou reconhece-lá como correta, desta forma outros com a mesma dúvida identificarão o que lhe ajudou.

Comment: Só queria informar que existem outras alternativas além do Firebase, Azure, e AWS, bem mais em conta.. Não quero fazer propaganda mas aonde trabalhava antes a gente usava o [SmartAsp](http://www.smarterasp.net/hosting_plans), claro que isto depende da quantidade de usuários que vão usar o app.

Comment: Isso se você for usar um serviço, nada impede também de você  desenvolver e hospedar seu próprio back-end. (Eu considero o Firebase uma boa alternativa, pois eles tem um plano gratuito muito bom,  não é sempre que queremos lançar um APP que logo no início já tenha um custo mensal de manutenção)